# BOM comparison sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, comparison

I have been working on Comparison sheet, where i need to compare Base BOM1 with other BOMS. I added formula & prepared the attached sheet & I am able to highlight the mismatch values. But i need the "mismatch values". Can someone help me to understand where i am making mistake. Please refer the image attached at http://tinypic.com/r/2n5547/8

**Formula in Cell K6 is =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B6,$C$6:$C$810,0)),"",B6)**

Can i get the values in place of RED FILLED CELLS

Answer (score 0):

From the formula you supplied :

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B6,$C$6:$C$810,0)),"",B6)
```

The cell will display a blank on error because its being told to (the `""` part of the formula). Try changing it to :

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B6,$C$6:$C$810,0)),C6,B6)
```

Comment: I tried, but now, it doesn't indicate the comparison. i.e, if you refer to last attachment (in cell K9, 4 is not matching at B9 & C9). I am looking for the value should also indicate and difference should also be highlighted. My intention is to highlight & indicate the mismatch values in the cells which can be anywhere in the 2 cells.